# Visibility cells of detail in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I have a problem in Reporting Services 2012.

I want get this tablix:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vATmh.jpg):https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5IEB.jpg

For this, I have a report with this tablix. There are two cells of detail, where "Base" is dynamic, the result query sql.

In the visibility second cell of detail, I have an expression:

```
iif(Previous(Fields!NOMBRE.Value)=Fields!NOMBRE.Value and RowNumber("DataSet1")=CountRows("DataSet1"),false,true)
```

But, my result is:

[image]

How can I do?

Comment: For clarification, I have a report with this tablix for question before: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilcKg.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood you correctly but you probably need to add a group with totals for 'Base'

Comment: Sorry, I don´t speak english very well. I think that it´s good idea but add a group with "Base", hapened this:

Comment: just delete the column that was created (but not the group)

Comment: It´s correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your expression will work only for the grand total because you are counting in the data set scope. You may need to count at group level. Suppose your group is called Detail then the expression should be:

```
iif(Previous(Fields!NOMBRE.Value)=Fields!NOMBRE.Value and RowNumber("Detail")=CountRows("Detail"),false,true)
```